# How to trigger semantic-release by a GitHub pull request?

Tags: github-actions, semantic-release

We are using the semantic-release tool for releasing. I want to create a GitHub action that runs on every PR and leaves a comment on the PR with the expected release version before merging it. I am trying the following GH workflow config (the GH PR commenting works well):

```yaml
name: Version Identification
 on:
   pull_request:
     branches:
       - '**'

 jobs:
   dry_run_release:
     name: Dry Release
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     permissions:
       contents: write
       issues: write
       pull-requests: write
     steps:
       - name: Checkout
         uses: actions/checkout@v3
       - name: Setup Node.js
         uses: actions/setup-node@v3
         with:
           node-version: "lts/*"
       - name: Install dependencies
         run: |
           npm install -g semantic-release conventional-changelog-conventionalcommits
       - name: Run Semantic Release with Dry Run
         env:
           GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
         run: |
           export DRY_RUN_BRANCH="dry-run/${GITHUB_REF}"
           git switch --force-create ${DRY_RUN_BRANCH}
           npx semantic-release --branches ${DRY_RUN_BRANCH} --no-ci --dry-run > .semver-output
           cat .semver-output
           export DRY_VERSION=$(cat .semver-output | grep "Published release" | cut -d' ' -f9)
           echo "DRY_VERSION=$DRY_VERSION" >> $GITHUB_ENV
           echo "The next release version would be $DRY_VERSION"
           git push origin --delete ${DRY_RUN_BRANCH}
```

But semantic-release fails on `This test run was triggered on the branch refs/pull/23/merge, while semantic-release is configured to only publish from dry-run/feat/pr-comment, therefore a new version won’t be published.` where `refs/pull/23/merge` is the `GITHUB_REF` and `feat/pr-comment` is my branch name.

So my question is: is there any way to run semantic-release on pull requests instead of branch pushes or is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Quite hacky and not sure this would be the best solution but this is what I could get to work for `pull_request` trigger only:

```
on:
  pull_request:
      branches:
          - main

jobs:
    pre-release:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with :
          fetch-depth: 0
          ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}
  
      - name: Setup Node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      - name: Semantic Release dry run
        id: semantic      
        run: |
          OUTPUT=$(unset GITHUB_ACTIONS && npx semantic-release --dry-run --no-ci --branches "${{ github.head_ref }}")
          VERSION=$(echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -o "The next release version is [0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" | awk '{print $6}')
          echo "::set-output name=version::$VERSION"
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          
      - name: Use the version
        run: echo "The version is ${{ steps.semantic.outputs.version }}"
```

Hope this helps!